# Is this "Westinghouse All Electric House" video, called a "promo from the mid 1950s", a hoax?

Tags: united-states, 1950s, electricity

This video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyrTgtPTz3M

It barely has any description, the comments are turned off, and the Wikipedia article on "Westinghouse Electric Company" does not help to clear anything up.

The video seems to be obviously filmed in the 1950s, but was it a serious "promo video" for an actual kitchen that (very rich) people could buy right there and then, a made-up hoax, or a sincere "this is coming soon" kind of video which they did expect to be possible soon?

A lot of the things they show aren't really too "fantastic" -- just costly. But the "heating the food in a few seconds" part gives me "fake" vibes...

Comment: There are [lots of references](https://www.google.com/search?ei=vUVEXty1FLSfytMP8sCp2A0&q=westinghouse+1959+house+of+the+future&oq=westinghouse+1959+house+of+the+future) to this video with more details.   "Heating the food in a few seconds" was a reference to the hot [pun intended] new technology we now know as the microwave.

Comment: "House of the future" mockups were all the rage in the fifties and sixties.  You can find a ton on Youtube.

Comment: Unfortunately this question would be considered "too basic", as it's pretty easy to find the answer on Google.

Comment: "Heating the food in a few seconds" is known as a [microwave oven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven); Westinghouse demonstrated their first radio-based oven in 1933, and Raytheon's first "Radarange" went on sale in 1947.